# How to use AMD files created by rollup

Tags: javascript, amd, rollup

I am using rollup to rollup some files:

```
{
  input: allFiles,
  output: {
    dir: 'distr/esm',
    format: 'esm'
  },
  plugins: [resolve({})]
},
```

A typical input file will be an ES6 class defining a custom element:

```
import { html } from 'lit-element'
import { NnInputText } from './nn-input-text'

class NnInputEmail extends NnInputText {
  render () {
    return html`
      ${this.customStyle}
      ${this.ifLabelBefore}
      ${this.ifValidationMessageBefore}
      <input type="email" id="native">
      ${this.ifValidationMessageAfter}
      ${this.ifLabelAfter}
    `
  }
}
window.customElements.define('nn-input-email', NnInputEmail)
```

In my HTML file I just have:

```
<script type="module" src="./distr/ems/nn-input-text.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine. However, I would like to make these elements available for older browsers. *I do realise that I need to run babel through them.*. However, in this post I am focussed on another issue -- the lack of ES6 module support for older browsers.

Rollup gives you the option to convert the modules to AMD:

```
{
  input: allFiles,
  output: {
    dir: 'distr/amd',
    format: 'amd'
  },
  plugins: [resolve({})]
},
```

However, the file then becomes:

```
define(['./lit-element-3745a578', './LabelsMixin-b14e4a18', './StyleableMixin-f8bc5e37', './ThemeableMixin-48d49b9b', './NativeReflectorMixin-d7c3df1b', './InputMixin-44a206df', './FormElementMixin-14a4dbcb', './nn-input-text'], function (litElement, LabelsMixin, StyleableMixin, ThemeableMixin, NativeReflectorMixin, InputMixin, FormElementMixin, nnInputText) { 'use strict';

  class NnInputEmail extends nnInputText.NnInputText {
    render () {
      return litElement.html`
      ${this.customStyle}
      ${this.ifLabelBefore}
      ${this.ifValidationMessageBefore}
      <input type="email" id="native">
      ${this.ifValidationMessageAfter}
      ${this.ifLabelAfter}
    `
    }
  }
  window.customElements.define('nn-input-email', NnInputEmail);

});
```

How I am meant to import this file into a browser to then use the custom element?
Do I need an AMD loader? If so, where do I get it from?

**UPDATE** I just tried this in my HTML file and... it worked?!?

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>

<script>
  require(['./distr/amd/themes/material/material.js', './distr/amd/nn-input-text.js'])
  </script>

<nn-input-text name="aName"></nn-input-text>
```

Surely... is this how I am meant to do it...?!?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out @merc?

Comment: See the update... maybe that IS the way to go after all. I guess the hope is that in 3/4 years 99.9% of browsers will support ES modules, and AMD support will finally be dropped. What a pain though...

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, for my case there was an alternative solution. I could use the umd option for rollup.

Comment: What's your solution....?

Comment: Sorry missed this notification completely. For my case I could use `format: 'umd'` as an option.

Comment: How do you actually use the generated file that comes out with `format: 'umd'` ?

Comment: That'd be a JS file with no 'funky' keywords in it, so I just use it as I'd use any other JS file.